What is wrong with this Nth from End code?
I can't seem to figure out this code. I've written a program but seem to get value errors when executing.
My issue is that depending on the formatting of the input I get an error
I'm trying to read a series of positive integers from a list, then a negative integer.
When the input is like this:
1 2 3 4 5
-6

it shows me a value error
but when it's input one at a time like this:
1
2
3
4
5
-6

I get the desired output.
Here is the commented code:
#Define a function find_nth_from_end, with parameters 'numbers' for positive numbers and 'n' representing the position fromt the end of the list
def find_nth_from_end(numbers,n):
    #Check if N is greater than the len of the list 'numbers'
    if n > len(numbers):
        #Return the negative of N
        return -n
    else:
        #If N is less than or equal to the range of the list, return the Nth number from end
        return numbers[-n]

#Store the main program in def main():
def main():
    #create an empty list to store positive numbers in 'numbers'
    numbers = []

    #Use a 'while' loop to receive the positive number inputs until a negative number is input
    while True:
        num = int(input())
        #Use an if statement to break the loop if num < 0
        if num < 0:
            #convert negative number to positive number to find N
            n = -num 
            break
        #Add positive number to list with .append
        numbers.append(num)

    #Find the Nth number from the end of the list
    result = find_nth_from_end(numbers, n)

    #Output result
    print(result)

#ensure program is run directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've tried rewrtiting the code several times,
here's one example:
def main():
    numbers=[]

    while True:
        numbers_list=input()
        numbers_int_list= [int(num) for num in numbers_list.split()]
    
        numbers.append(numbers_int_list)
        neg_num= int(input())
        if neg_num<0:
            n = -neg_num
            break
        numbers.append(neg_num)

    result = find_nth_from_end(numbers, n)

    print(result)

Now if I input the data like this:
1 2 3 4 5
-6

It will output -6
but if I input new data
1 5 9 7 5
-3

I get the output of -3 when I am expecting to get 9 as the output.

but seem to get value errors when executing Are we supposed to guess what these errors are?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which set of inputs is the program supposed to take? If it's supposed to take one per line, why were you surprised when it errored? If it's supposed to be multiple on one line, why does the next one need to be negative? If this is homework, read the requirements again closely. As for "what's wrong", there are two problems but they're are totally unrelated, and Stack Overflow is only built to handle one problem at a time, so you can [edit] if you want to clarify. See [ask] for more tips.

oops, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

@JohnGordon Looks like ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4 5'. But yeah, we shouldn't need to read the code to get that, it should be included in the question.

Partial duplicate: How to split a string of space separated numbers into integers?

Oops, I meant to say, "If it's supposed to be multiple on one line"... why do you need a while-loop and why are you taking neg_num in the loop?

For the first case, if you are entering 1 2 3 4 5 for the input, the variable is stored as a string "1 2 3 4 5" which can not be cast as a single int which throws the value error.
In your second case, you are doing slightly better by transforming the string '1 2 3 4 5' into a list where each element is also converted from string to int, so now you have the proper [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] input. However, the append doesn't work the way you think it does. It appends the whole list as a single element to the end of numbers, so numbers becomes [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] not [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], which only has one element! So naturally, asking for the 6th from the back gets -6. The same happens for your second input because it's still only a list of 1 (list) element.

This helped immensely! I edited some things and got the code to work! I appreciate it!
